# Are Shimano Claris brifters compatible with 90's Shimano 600 parts?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shifter

Is Claris backwards compatible with older shimano 600-tricolor? Can i just switch ill working parts with Claris since they are both 8 speed groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all Shimano 8-speed shifters and rear derailleurs except Dura-Ace are compatible. Road and off road front derailleurs have different cable pull, but since both 600 and Claris are road component series, they are compatible too.

Comment: I thought all shimano derailleurs <= 9 speeds (mtn or road) had the same pull ratio of 1.7, making them all interchangeable.

Comment: Reference: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/dura-ace.html#indexing